# How to use "enter" to separate input tokens in C?

Tags: c, stringtokenizer

Example user input:

abcd <kbd>enter</kbd> efgh <kbd>enter</kbd>

I want to extract the strings separated by presses of the <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

Comment: You can use a function like `fgets` to read a line of text (it will include the newline character).

Comment: fgets create buffer overflow no ? (I mean "can")

Comment: @Simon marc: no, `fgets` takes a `size` parameter: `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);`

Comment: @Simon: It is only problematic if you specify a size that is greater than the actual size of the buffer. Usually, if you have a stack-allocated buffer, i.e. `char buf[1000]`, you can specify `sizeof buf`, and if you have a heap allocated buffer (i.e. from `malloc`) then you have already calculated the size anyway.

Comment: Yes I know, I didn't look the man page of fgets. I always use read to have exactly memory needed and infinite string.

Answer (score 2):

What function are you using for read on 0 ? (I guess it's on 0). If it's read(), you normally read byte by byte, so when the user press enter, check if the byte is equal to '\n' (simple quote !).

Answer (score 1):

Use `getline` it's **safe**, strongly recommended instead of {f}gets

Or use `strtok` with '\n' as a delimiter

http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just read whole lines using `fgets` or `scanf`